# How to get a transfer function from this block diagram?

Tags: transfer-function, diagram

Pardon my paint skills, I did my best
[image]

My attempt is short and seems to fail, I have no idea why:

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= in - a_{1}\beta - a_{2}\gamma \\
\beta &= \alpha z^{-1} \\
\gamma &= \beta z^{-1} = \alpha z^{-2}
\end{align}$$

inputting 2nd and 3rd equation into the first one I get:

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= in - a_{1}\alpha z^{-1} - a_{2}\alpha z^{-2} \\
in &= \alpha + a_{1}\alpha z^{-1} + a_{2}\alpha z^{-2}
\end{align}$$

I can write the output as:

$$\begin{align}
out &= b_{2}\gamma + b_{1}\beta + b_{0}\alpha \\
out &= b_{2}\alpha z^{-2} + b_{1}\alpha z^{-1} + b_{0}\alpha
\end{align}$$

I have output and input in terms of alpha, but I can't figure what to do from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going in the right direction! Lets take these two equations:
$$(1) \quad in = \alpha+a_1\alpha z^{-1}+a_2\alpha z^{-2}$$
$$(2) \quad out = b_0\alpha+b_1\alpha z^{-1}+b_2\alpha z^{-2}$$
now rewrite (1) such that it becomes a function of $\alpha$:
$$in = \alpha\left(1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}\right)$$
$$\alpha = \frac{in}{1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}}$$
Substitute $\alpha$ in equation (2):
$$out = in\frac{b_0+b_1 z^{-1}+b_2 z^{-2}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}}$$
And derive proper discrete transfer function from it:
$$H(z) = \frac{out}{in} = \frac{b_0+b_1 z^{-1}+b_2 z^{-2}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}}$$

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I'm ashamed I didn't figure it out myself. 
But you made a little mistake I believe, in the second (2) equation the last term should have b2 instead of a2, and that mistakes propagates to the results as well

Comment: Oops, small copy-past error haha. fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that you could use [this](https://www.diagrams.net/) to draw diagrams next time. Much easier to use than paint. You can even use [Latex](https://www.diagrams.net/blog/maths-in-diagrams).

Comment: This really should be posted as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Don't have the reputation to do so, just need 4 more to get to 50 lol

Comment: Just one good answer will get you there!

Comment: If you used this website to draw a new diagramm for thr op and then answer the OPs question i’d definitely +1